# make_scorer (from sklearn.metrics) for multi-class logarithmic loss

Tags: python, scoring

I got the following code for the Root mean squared logarithmic errorL

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

def rmsele(actual, pred):
    squared_errors = (np.log(pred + 1) - np.log(actual + 1)) ** 2
    mean_squared = np.sum(squared_errors) / len(squared_errors)
    return np.sqrt(mean_squared)

rmsele_scorer = make_scorer(rmsele, greater_is_better=False)
```

I'd like to have one for multi-class logarithmic loss.  Could someone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Please show the code in which you failed to properly implement the multi-class math.